# Evaluate $\int_{\mathbb R^p}e^{-t\|Ax\|_2^2}d\lambda_p(x)$ for invertible $A \in \mathbb R^{p \times p}$ and $t>0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{p \times p}$ be an invertible $p \times p$ matrix and $t>0.$

How can I evaluate $\int_{\mathbb R^p}e^{-t\|Ax\|_2^2}d\lambda_p(x)$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}\int_{[-1,1]^p}e^{-t\|Ax\|_2^2}$?

$[-1,1]^p=[-1,1]\times\dots\times[-1,1]$

$f:\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R, f(x)=e^{-t\|x\|_2^2}$

$T: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^p, T(x)=Ax$

$\int_{\mathbb R^p}f(x)d\lambda_p(x)=|\det A|\int_{\mathbb R^p}f\circ T(x) d\lambda_p(x)$

So, $\int_{\mathbb R^p}e^{-t\|Ax\|_2^2}d\lambda_p(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^p}f \circ T(x)d\lambda_p(x)=\frac{1}{|\det A|}\int_{\mathbb R^p}f(x)d\lambda_p(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

- If $T$ is a linear map, then $$\int_V f(Tx)\mu(\mathrm dx)=\int_{TV}f(u)(\mu\circ T^{-1})(\mathrm du).$$

If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then $$(\mu\circ T^{-1})(\mathrm du)=|\det(T^{-1})|\,\mathrm d u.$$

- For the limit, dominated convergence works.

Comment: See my edit, that's what I tried. I think it is the same as your hint. But how can I continue?

Comment: Then you get $\frac{1}{|\det(A)|^{-1}}\prod_{i=1}^p\int_{-1}^1e^{-tx^2}\,\  d x$ and you can't go farther (this is a special function).@user700332

Comment: Don't you mean $|\det(A)|^{-1}\prod_{i=1}^p\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-tx_i^2}dx$?

Comment: @user700332: Yes you right. Sorry.

Comment: And for the limit: $\lim_{t \to 0} e^{-t\|Ax\|_2^2}=1$ and $e^{-t \|Ax\|_2^2}$ is integrable over $[-1,1]$ so we can use dominate convergence. And the solution is $2^p$?

Comment: the argument to use DCT is not correct. But the answer is correct.

Comment: how would the correct argument look like?

Comment: If $t>0$, then $e^{-t\|x\|}\leq 1\in L^1([-1,1]^p)$.